# Show message on click of a button in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview, a label and a Button in ASP.net. 
If the total number of records in the gridview is more than 500 and if the user clicks on the button, a message "You cannot print more than 500 records at one time".

How can I do this in ASP.net. If it is less than 500 it is currently generating a PDF.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Comment: acadia, you should've specified the extra details you provided on SLaks answer in your original question.  It looks like you are a bit newer here...  so you can edit your question and add the details above.  This helps others greatly when trying to answer your question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (grid.Rows.Count > 500) {
    label.Text = "You cannot print more than 500 records at one time";
} else {
    //Export a PDF
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more detail.

Comment: Problem is grid.rows.count will give the total for the current page. I have pagination enabled. and I want it as message box and not on the label.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want something like this in the code behind file:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.myGridView.Rows.Count > 500)
    {
        this.myLabel.Text = "You can not print more than 500 records";
    }
    else
    {
         // Print the PDF
    }
}
```

Now on the ASP side of things you hook these up like so:

```
<asp:button id="myButton" onclick="Button_Click" runat="server" text="Print PDF of Grid" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get your records, examine the count of the records. Then, if it's more than 500, add a javascript alert to the button like this:

```
If records.Count > 500 Then
  btnPrint.Attributes("onclick") = "alert('You cannot print more than 500 records at one time.'); return false;"
Else
  btnPrint.Attributes("onclick") = ""
End If
```